# Defining friendships in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, graph, cluster-analysis

I have a task in which it is necessary to determine the presence of a friendly connection. Let me explain, there is a checkpoint at work. The employee, passing through it, gets into the database, where his time of passage and his name are recorded. If an employee often passes through the point with the same person, then it is possible to assume with some probability that there is a friendly relationship between them. It is also necessary to take into account the difference in time with which they passed, if the difference in the passage is large, then they probably did not even see each other. For example, I made a small time Series:

```
    import pandas as pd
dict_df={
    'Data':['2020-02-10 10:00:23','2020-02-10 10:01:23','2020-02-10 10:01:30','2020-02-10 10:01:43',
            '2020-02-10 10:02:02','2020-02-10 10:02:30','2020-02-10 10:02:35','2020-02-10 10:02:50',
            '2020-02-10 10:02:58','2020-02-10 10:03:02','2020-02-10 10:03:10','2020-02-10 10:03:15',
            '2020-02-10 10:03:26','2020-02-10 10:03:32','2020-02-10 10:03:38','2020-02-10 10:03:40',
            '2020-02-10 10:03:46','2020-02-10 10:03:50','2020-02-10 10:04:04','2020-02-10 10:04:12',
            '2020-02-10 10:04:23','2020-02-10 10:04:27','2020-02-10 10:04:45','2020-02-10 10:04:50',
            '2020-02-10 10:04:59','2020-02-10 10:05:20','2020-02-10 10:05:26','2020-02-10 10:05:40',
            '2020-02-10 10:05:56','2020-02-10 10:06:12','2020-02-10 10:06:18','2020-02-10 10:06:30',
            '2020-02-10 10:06:37'],
    'Name':['Ann','Jhon','Chase','Bruce','Evan','Fred','Hugh','Gregory','Jack','Caleb','Eric','James',
            'Ann','Gerld','Jess','Juan','Luke','Kyle','Neil','Owen','James','Eric','Jhon','Jess','Norman',
            'Hugh','Fred','Gregory','Ryan','Angel','Cole','James','Eric']}

df=pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
```

This is what it looks like:

```
 Data                Name
0   2020-02-10 10:00:23 Ann
1   2020-02-10 10:01:23 Jhon
2   2020-02-10 10:01:30 Chase
3   2020-02-10 10:01:43 Bruce
4   2020-02-10 10:02:02 Evan
5   2020-02-10 10:02:30 Fred
6   2020-02-10 10:02:35 Hugh
7   2020-02-10 10:02:50 Gregory
8   2020-02-10 10:02:58 Jack
9   2020-02-10 10:03:02 Caleb
10  2020-02-10 10:03:10 Eric
11  2020-02-10 10:03:15 James
12  2020-02-10 10:03:26 Ann
13  2020-02-10 10:03:32 Gerld
14  2020-02-10 10:03:38 Jess
15  2020-02-10 10:03:40 Juan
16  2020-02-10 10:03:46 Luke
17  2020-02-10 10:03:50 Kyle
18  2020-02-10 10:04:04 Neil
19  2020-02-10 10:04:12 Owen
20  2020-02-10 10:04:23 James
21  2020-02-10 10:04:27 Eric
22  2020-02-10 10:04:45 Jhon
23  2020-02-10 10:04:50 Jess
24  2020-02-10 10:04:59 Norman
25  2020-02-10 10:05:20 Hugh
26  2020-02-10 10:05:26 Fred
27  2020-02-10 10:05:40 Gregory
28  2020-02-10 10:05:56 Ryan
29  2020-02-10 10:06:12 Angel
30  2020-02-10 10:06:18 Cole
31  2020-02-10 10:06:30 James
32  2020-02-10 10:06:37 Eric
```

I need it to be like this:

```
 Data                Name   cluster
0   2020-02-10 10:00:23 Ann     0
1   2020-02-10 10:01:23 Jhon    0
2   2020-02-10 10:01:30 Chase   0
3   2020-02-10 10:01:43 Bruce   0
4   2020-02-10 10:02:02 Evan    0
5   2020-02-10 10:02:30 Fred    1
6   2020-02-10 10:02:35 Hugh    1
7   2020-02-10 10:02:50 Gregory 1
8   2020-02-10 10:02:58 Jack    0
9   2020-02-10 10:03:02 Caleb   0
10  2020-02-10 10:03:10 Eric    2
11  2020-02-10 10:03:15 James   2
12  2020-02-10 10:03:26 Ann     0
13  2020-02-10 10:03:32 Gerld   0
14  2020-02-10 10:03:38 Jess    0
15  2020-02-10 10:03:40 Juan    0
16  2020-02-10 10:03:46 Luke    0
17  2020-02-10 10:03:50 Kyle    0
18  2020-02-10 10:04:04 Neil    0
19  2020-02-10 10:04:12 Owen    0
20  2020-02-10 10:04:23 James   2
21  2020-02-10 10:04:27 Eric    2
22  2020-02-10 10:04:45 Jhon    0
23  2020-02-10 10:04:50 Jess    0
24  2020-02-10 10:04:59 Norman  0
25  2020-02-10 10:05:20 Hugh    1
26  2020-02-10 10:05:26 Fred    1
27  2020-02-10 10:05:40 Gregory 1
28  2020-02-10 10:05:56 Ryan    0
29  2020-02-10 10:06:12 Angel   0
30  2020-02-10 10:06:18 Cole    0
31  2020-02-10 10:06:30 James   2
32  2020-02-10 10:06:37 Eric    2
```

You can see that Fred, Gregory and Hugh have passed together several times, so a friendly connection is established. Also, James and Eric passed together, so it is also a friendly relationship.

Help us solve it using machine learning, say clustering or graph analysis. Tell me, maybe someone has thoughts.

Comment: In my opinion, as you have already stated what counts as a friendly relationship(and that condition is not very complicated  I'd suggest you make a function where you pass it the timeseries, and then check how many times a person passes the checkpoint together with a person. If that number is greater than X, you have a friendly relationship. 

If you want to use clustering, there are several libraries that are easy to use. Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for clustering algorithms.  Such algorithms are useful if your data has multiple traits.  In this case, there is only one: arrival time.    Simply keep track of how often pairs arrive "together".

```
loop over arrivals
   loop over previous arrivals, recent enough to be friends
       increment count for this pair
loop over pairs
   if count above minimum, mark as friends
```

Setting the maximum time between friends arriving to be 20 secs, and the minimum frequency for a pair to be recognized as friends to be 2, then we get:

```
togerther count:
Angel Cole 1
Angel James 1
Ann Gerld 1
Ann Jess 1
Ann Juan 1
Ann Luke 1
Bruce Evan 1
Caleb Eric 1
Caleb James 1
Chase Bruce 1
Cole Eric 1
Cole James 1
Eric Ann 1
Eric James 3
Eric Jhon 1
Fred Gregory 2
Fred Hugh 2
Gerld Jess 1
Gerld Juan 1
Gerld Kyle 1
Gerld Luke 1
Gregory Caleb 1
Gregory Eric 1
Gregory Jack 1
Gregory Ryan 1
Hugh Gregory 2
Jack Caleb 1
Jack Eric 1
Jack James 1
James Ann 1
James Gerld 1
Jess Juan 1
Jess Kyle 1
Jess Luke 1
Jess Norman 1
Jhon Bruce 1
Jhon Chase 1
Jhon Jess 1
Jhon Norman 1
Juan Kyle 1
Juan Luke 1
Kyle Neil 1
Luke Kyle 1
Luke Neil 1
Neil James 1
Neil Owen 1
Owen Eric 1
Owen James 1
Ryan Angel 1
```

and so the friends are

```
friends:
Eric James 3
Fred Gregory 2
Fred Hugh 2
Hugh Gregory 2
```

You can see C++ code implementing this at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/cba0a5e8bbda9388c3e983c3bc5dfd9b